# Using an external library in an angularjs project - MathJax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax

I try to use MathJax library in my angularjs project.

I don't want to use `<script type="text/javascript">` into index.html to add the library but I want something like this:

```
 angular.module('mymodule', ['MathJax'])
```

How could this be done?

**edit**
I already installed MathJax in my project using bower.

Answer (score 1):

You've to use both.
The first one loads the library on the client browser, if you only use this an error will be displayed when you try to use the library because it's not injected as a module on AngularJs.
The second injects the functionality on the AngularJs context, if you only use the error would be module not found.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to inject this library as a module into your application. If you really want to do it this way, you need to create a custom module using the source code from MathJax. Honestly, I can see no valid reason to do this but, if you insist on doing it that way, there are tutorials available online about creating custom modules.

Angular doc on modules: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module